# How to fetch user information from instagram without user authendication using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to fetch user information from instagram but now instagram sending request to the user to allow me to fetch their information and then only I can get their data

Will there be any way to make this process App to App communication without user concern

**GET AUTH CODE**

```
app.get("/get-auth-code", (req, res, next) => {
console.log(INSTA_REDIRECT_URI);
return res.send(
`<a href='https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?  client_id=${INSTA_APP_ID}&redirect_uri=${INSTA_REDIRECT_URI}&scope=user_media,user_profile&response_type=code'> Connect to Instagram </a>`
  );
 });
```

**To Get Access Token From Instagram API**

```
app.get("/getAccessToken",asyncHandler((req, res, next) => {
    request.post(
      {
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
        form: {
          redirect_uri: INSTA_REDIRECT_URI,
          client_id: INSTA_APP_ID,
          client_secret: INSTA_APP_SECRET,
          code: INSTA_AUTH_CODE,
          grant_type: "authorization_code",
       },
     },
      function (err, httpResponse, body) {
        /* ... */
        console.log("err: " + err);
        console.log("body: " + body);
        return res.status(200).json(body);
      }
    );
  })
);
```

To Get User Details from Instagram API

```
app.get("/getDetail",asyncHandler((req, res, next) => {
    request.get(
      {
         url: `https://graph.instagram.com/${INSTA_USER_ID}? 
               fields=id,username,media_type&access_token=${INSTA_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      },
      function (err, httpResponse, body) {
         /* ... */
        console.log("err: " + err);
        console.log("body: " + body);
        return res.status(200).json(body);
      }
    );
  })
);
```

So the point is to get users information without getting permission from the user , Is there any way to do this

Comment: Hopefully not...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to fetch user's data without consent

Comment: will it be possible if I verify my app to instagram and get the permission , because in this process there is a manual authendication is there, I want to avoid that